# Feature usage for machine learning algorithm

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-extraction

Given a list of software installed by users as features, e.g.,

> Microsoft_VC80_DebugCRT_x86_x64 1.0.0
>   Microsoft_VC80_DebugCRT_x86 1.0.0
>   Windows UPnP Browser 0.1.01
>   Adobe Acrobat Professional 10

I want to predict whether the student will buy certain product.

Now the question is: what are the ways to turn the list of software into something learnable by a machine learning algorithm?

Comment: There are many different ways to do that - what features you'd want to extract are based in part on your understanding of the problem. For example, should the first two you list be treated as the same? If I'm interpreting you correctly, you actually have two questions: 1) from a ML perspective, what are the different types of features you could create from text? (which would be better posted on [another site](http://stats.stackexchange.com) or researched through Google.) 2) How do you do that in python - probably some form of tfidf, which would likely be a duplicate question.

Comment: @william007 In addition to things Tchotchke said, a hint would be to make your data [tidy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidy_data), especially differentiate among these concepts in feature extraction: Software Vendor(Microsoft, Adobe, etc), Software(VC80_DebugCRT, Acrobat, etc), Version, Architecture(x86, x64, etc), OS(Windows, Linux, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach is to use a [vectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#text-feature-extraction) from scikit learn.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

#min_df is the minimum number of students 
#that have to have a piece of software installed to be included in 
#the feature set

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(min_df=1)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(data)
```

The vectorizer will construct a vector where each column maps to one of the 'terms' in your data set (here, a piece of software) and the value will be the number of times that term appears for a particular student. Each student will now be represented by a vector. These vectors can be fed in as features to most of the algorithms supported by scikit-learn.